# Angular 7 Nested Components

Tags: angular, angular7, angular2-components

I'm a guy with experience in WPF.
And now i decided to try web development

And someone that learn from experience and hands on instead of reading

I'm trying to create a simple web app.

Angular 7 that uses bootstrap 4

So i created a simple Angular App installed bootstrap 4 then copied the code of the dashboard.html with modification of this template https://www.creative-tim.com/product/material-dashboard i know that there is an Angular version for this template but i want to learn how things work.

I have successfully used the template in the angular app

[Template Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iB7h4.png)

But i want to separate the navigation of the template

So i added a component named `nav` and pasted the code in it

```
<li class="nav-item active  ">
            <a class="nav-link" href="./dashboard.html">
              <i class="material-icons">dashboard</i>
              <p>Dashboard</p>
            </a>
          </li>
```

Then this is the code for my app.component.html

```
<div class="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="nav">
            <nav></nav>

        </ul>
      </div>
```

But the navigation is not showing in my Web this is what is look like now

[Screenshot of the component that is not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4g9lm.png)

This is the code for `app.module.ts`

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavComponent } from './nav/nav.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

What are the things that i missed?

If i need to post code from another file. Please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would need the full code for the nav component to be sure, but an educated guess would be that you need to use `<app-nav></app-nav>` instead. Check the selector property of your nav component

Comment: owww. I'm very sorry. I used the <nav></nav> but in my selector: 'app-nav' so i should use the one in the selector. Thank you so much.